# C#. Можно ли паралельно загружать данные используя EF?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

`DbContext` не является потокобезопасным, можно ли считывать данные из базы данных паралельно в разных потоках используя один объект? Или нужно создавать отдельный экземпляр `DbContext`? Или может в EF есть какой-то более грамотный способ параллельной загрузки большого объема данных?

Нужно выполнить два запроса, каждый выполняется примерно 3 секунды, и того выходит примерно 6-7 секунд на обработку запроса пользователя. Хотелось бы уменьшить это время.

Можно ли 1 большой запрос разделить на 2? Например если select из базы данных выполняется 3 секунды. Можно ли половину данных загрузить одним запросом, а другую половину другим (есть ли в этом смысл)?

Comment: `Можно ли половину данных загрузить одним запросом, а другую половину другим (есть ли в этом смысл)?` - хм, а кто гарантирует, что результаты двух запросов дадут в сумме один полный? Как это вообще можно добиться?

Comment: @АндрейNOP например сначала можно загрузить первые 200000 записей, затем остальные

Comment: А что значит "первые"? Данные надо как-то упорядочить перед этим, это создаст еще больше накладных расходов. Да и "затем остальные" - сначала переберет то что пропускаем, думаю... Вообще, зачем загружать 200 000 записей? Что с ними делать? Ни один GUI такого не потерпит :)

Comment: Если количество записей велико, например начинает тормозить UI при отображении, то действительно делают постраничную загрузку. Вы это хотели узнать?

Comment: @Bulson UI не глючит, мне нужно ускорить получение данных устройством. Обработка данных и так занимает много времени, уменьшить его на 3-4 секунды было бы неплохо.

Comment: @АндрейNOP по моему мнению первый запрос должен выглядеть как-то так: `_entities.Take(200000).ToListAsync();` , а второй так `_entities.Skip(200000).ToListAsync();` Загружаем первые 200000, затем остальные (запросы выполнять параллельно)

Comment: @mirypoko, ок, но БД не гарантирует, что порядок возврата данных в этих двух вопросах будет одинаковый, поэтому во втором может оказаться часть данных из первого, а какая-то часть может не попасть ни в один из них

Comment: У вас, похоже, неправильное понимание работы с СУБД. Первое и основное правило: максимум работы с данными должен производить сервер СУБД, а не клиентское приложение, приложение должно не анализировать данные, а лишь только их отображать. Потому никто и никогда не выгружает на клиентскую сторону всю инфо из БД, грузят по минимуму, только самое необходимое.

Comment: @АндрейNOP данные в базе данных отсортированы по целочисленному индексу, вроде порядок не должен нарушаться.

Comment: @mirypoko, "вроде", но это не гарантируется

Comment: @mirypoko, думаю, если скорости EF вам перестало хватать, самое время от него отказаться. Пишите SQL вручную и оптимизируйте его

Comment: @АндрейNOP Я подозреваю, что дело не в SQL-запросе, а в архитектуре. Постоянно делается выборка из таблицы, которая обновляется => выборка ждет, пока все блокировки пройдут. Поможет только смена архитектуры...

Comment: @АндрейNOP отказываться от ef не обязательно, можно *тяжелые* запросы написать ручками, а ef оставить все остальное

Comment: @Bald, это то же самое, просто отказаться *частично*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сомневаюсь, что разбивая 1 запрос на несколько маленьких, каждый из которых возвращает какой-то кусок вы получите какую-то выигрыш во времени. Да и вообще, с точки зрения СУБД ей проще выполнить 1 большой запрос, чем несколько запросов по N записей => производительность будет меньше.

НО, если цель вывести на UI одну часть данных, а потом дополнить другой частью данных, то тут выигрыш будет, так как юзер уже сейчас сможет начинать работать.

По таком принципу работают, например запросы в Access, выдавая часть результата, а затем подгружая новые записи.

Однако, есть и другие пути решения проблемы:

1. Не может ли у вас быть проблемы со скоростью сети?
2. Есть ли все необходимые индексы?
3. Помониторьте Profiler'ом какой запрос шлется на сервер. Быть может он монструозный и если вы разобьете свое LINQ выражение на маленькие, то получите более оптимизированный запрос.

Comment: Записи имеют целочисленные id и отсортированы по нему. С сетью нормальная (обычно интернет есть). Запрос очень простой и состоит из select к таблице. Таких запросов 2. Могут суммарно выполняться 6-30 секунд (как повезет) Запросы нужно периодически повторять (хотелось бы раз в 10 минут). Была мысль загружать все данные 1 раз, а потом загружать только изменения. Но изменений много и нужно как-то сравнивать клиентскую бд с серверной, проще все по новой загрузить.

Comment: Вы уверены, что пользователи нужны все данные? Может их динамически подгружать?

Comment: Точно обычный SELECT? А то EF любит каскады из SELECT FROM(SELECT FROM ...) строить при каких-нибудь JOIN'ах

Comment: Еще данные могут долго выбираться из-за частых обновлений. Так как SELECT *  ждет пока снимутся блокировки с обновляемых записей. Скорее всего- это узкое место, так как как вы говорите время выполнения запроса скачет.